# How to avoid jsPlumb connectors break off while dragging the dynamically created divs

Tags: connector, jsplumb

I am new to jsPlumb. I have created dynamic divs by reading a table from database and I have connected these divs by using JsPlumb connectors. The divs have been made draggable. The connectors are showing up correctly when the page loads, but when I drag or move the divs the connectors breaks off and moved to top. If I create a static divs which are not coming from database then the connectors are working perfectly and when I drag/move the divs then the connectors are also moving along the divs connected to source and target divs.

After doing a complete search on google and by going through jsPlumb documents, I did not find any solution for this.

Can anyone tell me as what should be done to have the connectors stay connected to source and destination even when we drag or move the divs.

Here is what I have done:

JsPlumb Code for one connection:

jsPlumb.ready(function() {

```
                 jsPlumb.connect({
                     source: "FDiv1",
                     target: "IDiv1",
                     connector: ["Flowchart"],
                     anchors: ["RightMiddle", "LeftMiddle"],
                     paintStyle: {
                         lineWidth: 2,
                         strokeStyle: "rgb(189, 11, 50)",
                         outlineColor: "#666",
                         outlineWidth: 1
                     },
                     hoverPaintStyle: { strokeStyle: "#7ec3d9" },
                     detachable: false,
                     endpoint: "Blank",
                     endpointsOnTop: false,
                     deleteEndpointsOnDetach: false,
                     endpointStyle: { fillStyle: "#a7b04b" },
                     overlays: [ "Arrow" ]
                 });

                 jsPlumb.draggable($(".bg"));
    });
```

I have hardcoded the source and target here which later I should be getting these dynamically to connect all other divs.

Here is the dynamic divs code in code behind.

foreach (DataRow dt in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {

```
            HtmlGenericControl myDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            HtmlGenericControl myDiv2 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

            //********Source Div**************

            myDiv.ID = "FDiv" + j;

            myDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "bg");
            myDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginLeft, "30px");
            myDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginTop, top + "px");
            myDiv.InnerHtml = "Filename: " + dt["Column1"].ToString() + "<br>" + myDiv.ID;
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myDiv);


            //************Target Div****************

            myDiv2.ID = "IDiv" + j;

            myDiv2.Attributes.Add("class", "bg");
            myDiv2.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginLeft, "260px");
            myDiv2.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginTop, top + "px");
            myDiv2.InnerHtml = "Filename: " + dt["Column2"].ToString() + "<br>" + myDiv2.ID;
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myDiv2);

            top = top + 140;
            j = j + 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the DIV draggable as jsPlumb.draggable($(".bg"));
Try making the DIV draggable during its creation.
i.e.

**Source Div**

```
        myDiv.ID = "FDiv" + j;

        myDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "bg");
        myDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginLeft, "30px");
        myDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginTop, top + "px");
        myDiv.InnerHtml = "Filename: " + dt["Column1"].ToString() + "<br>" + myDiv.ID;
        jsPlumb.draggable($('#FDiv' + j)); // make it draggable
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myDiv);
```

`
||y for target DIV

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with dynamically created divs and solved it by not using jsPlumb.draggable(element) but instead jQuery and jsPumb.repaint(element) as follows (the example is a bit overkill with the use of repaint but you get the picture):

```
element.draggable({
    step: function () {
        jsPlumb.repaint(element);
    },
    drag:function(){
        jsPlumb.repaint(element);
    },
    stop:function(){
        jsPlumb.repaint(element);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps you.